# What does: string $string[, int $length]) mean in PHP?

Tags: php

The following statement is taken from the PHP manual online:

> Int fwrite( resource $handle, string $string[, int $length])

I understand that `fwrite` is a function
that returns an `int`, takes a resource called `$handle`.

But what is: `string $string [, int $length ]`?

Is that an array? What is the comma for?

Comment: *string* is the type of data, *$string* is the data itself, and anything inside square brackets are optional values (meaning you don't have to necessarily set them for the function to work, but you should if you have specific needs).

Comment: and it should be separated with comma..

Answer (score 3):

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/about.prototypes.php) for methods is usually written in this way

```
int fwrite ( resource $handle , string $string [, int $length ] )
↑                ↑               ↑             ↑ optional parameters are inside []
|                |               |
|                |---------------| Types parameters should be
|                                                   
| Return Type of method
```

Comment: As always, reading the manual page is the shortest answer :]

Comment: @Rizier123: Ah!  A manual link about to read the manual.  So meta.  Thanks :-)  P.S. Thanks for the `↑` instead of `^`.

Answer (score 1):

`string` is the type of data you may pass as parameter, `$string` is the parameter data itself, and anything inside `[square brackets]` are comma-separated **optional values** (meaning you don't have to *necessarily* set them for the function to return something, but you should if you have *specific needs*).

Answer (score 0):

`resource $handle :`  will get a param with resource type

`string $string:` will get a param with string type

Inside square brackets are optional values. You can send theese parameters or not. And you should seperate theese params via commas.

Answer (score 0):

`string` means that the `$string` variable is typed as String. The parameters that are inside the brackets are optional, and you don't need to pass any of those to the function call.

Please note that if more than one parameter is optional, you will have to use the function in such way that the parameters maintain the order, you cannot pass the third optional parameter without passing the first and second (even though they are optional).